# Pregunta sobre ejercicio de Arrays en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo una duda sobre javascript, que cuando hago una prueba me devuelve undefined deepEquap "oro" por ejemplo, si hago medallaSegunPuesto(1), no entiendo que es este error asi que si me pueden explicar que es y que esta mal se lo agradecería. Básicamente tengo que pasar por parámetro un puesto y la función tiene que devolverme la medalla que corresponda

```
   function medallaSegunPuesto(puesto){

       var puestos = ["oro", "plata", "bronce", "nada", "nada"];

       var posicion = puestos.indexOf(puestos[puesto]);

       if((posicion + 1) == puesto){
               console.log(puestos[puesto]);
       }


     }
```

Comment: El parámetro `puesto` es el index de cada item o el nombre? No consigo entender que quieres hacer. :(

Comment: Hola, te invito a repasar [ask]. Tu pregunta no está del todo clara, sin embargo creo que entiendo que `puesto` se refiere a una posición en alguna competencia. Dado que los puestos que merecen medalla (tomando por ejemplo las competiciones deportivas) son del primer al tercer puesto, no veo la necesidad de agregar más de tres medallas en tu `Array` de puestos. Por otro lado, dado que Javascript maneja índices a partir de cero, cada vez que pases un puesto por parámetro deberás restar 1 posición si deseas acceder al valor del mismo en el `Array`. Por otro lado, tu función no devuelve nada.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que te estabas complicando un poco. Se puede simplificar el problema usando el número que se entrega como parámetro de entrada a la función para acceder directamente al `array` y restarle a este uno ya que las posiciones de un `array` comienzan en **0**.

```js
function medallaSegunPuesto(puesto) {
  var puestos = ["oro", "plata", "bronce"];
  
  //Se accede a la posición del array que corresponda según el puesto recibido
  var puesto_devuelto = puestos[puesto-1];
  
  //Se comprueba que el puesto elegido entre dentro del rango permitido por el array,
  //devolviéndose un mensaje de error de no ser el caso.
  if (puesto_devuelto === undefined) {
    return 'Los puestos están comprendidos entre 1 y 3. Selecciona un puesto válido'
  }
  else {
    return puesto_devuelto;
  }
 }
 
 //Llamada con parámetro fuera del rango de medallas.
 console.log(medallaSegunPuesto (0));
 
 //Llamada con resultado dentro del ranfo de medallas.
 console.log(medallaSegunPuesto (1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que un `Array` comienza a contar desde la posición **0**, y desde ahí va sumando. Por tanto, dentro de tu `puesto`, tienes que tener en cuenta que al valor que añadas, tienes que restarle 1.

En tu código, además tienes una comparación que no tiene sentido:

```
var posicion = puestos.indexOf(puestos[puesto]);

if((posicion + 1) == puesto){
    console.log(puestos[puesto]);
}
```

Si pasas el valor **1** a `puestos.indexOf(puestos[puesto])` estarás devolviendo el índice de `plata` constantemente, que es 1. Si `posición + 1 == puesto`, entonces 1 + 1 == 1, que es false siempre.

He hecho un pequeño script que permita añadir cualquier posición y devuelva la respuesta que esperas.

```js
const puestosPrueba = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const medallaSegunPuesto = puesto => {
  const puestos = ['oro', 'plata', 'bronce'];
  return puestos[puesto - 1] || 'nada';
}

puestosPrueba.forEach(puesto => console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(puesto)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices `var posicion = puestos.indexOf(puestos[puesto])` lo que está pasando esto:

`puestos[puesto]` devuelve 'plata'

`puestos.indexOf(puestos[puesto])` busca el índice de 'plata' es decir `posición` valdrá 1

Al poner luego  `if ((posicion + 1) == puesto)` estás diciendo `if (1+1==1)` por lo que nunca se cumplirá

De todas formas, si quieres que te devuelva la medalla puedes ponerlo así:

```
function medallaSegunPuesto(puesto){
    var puestos = ["oro", "plata", "bronce"];
    return puestos[puesto-1] || 'nada'

}

console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(1))  >> 'oro'
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(2))  >> 'plata'  
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(3))  >> 'bronce'
console.log(medallaSegunPuesto(4))  >> 'nada'
```

Comment: Por favor, si vas a modificar tu respuesta usando el codigo ingresado en otras respuestas, ten la delicadeza de dar los creditos necesarios a quien escribio el codigo original ;).

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, disculpa no haber puesto nada, pero es que no había visto que habían puesto ya lo mismo que yo. Suelo escribir el código y luego hacer pruebas y mejorar la respuesta y así ha sido esta vez. Sinceramente ha sido una coincidencia (puedes ver todas mis respuestas para ver que nunca he hecho nada así y que suelo responder y luego mejorar las respuestas).

Comment: No hay ningun problema. Lo comento porque causo confusion y "parecio" una copia.. no hay ningun problema en que se te haya ocurrido lo mismo y hasta es lógico.. Sono muy raro (sabras entender) que tu codigo haya quedado exactamente igual a otros ya escritos, inclusive editada tu respuesta luego del ingreso de otras respuestas. Pero confiamos en tu buena voluntad. :)